# Is large language model and foundation model the same thing?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, large-language-models

I read a lot about foundation model and large language model.

However, I dont find a clear definition what exactly is a foundation model. Is large language model and foundation model the same thing?

Answer (score 9):

At this point in time, there does not appear to be a really widely-agreed-upon definition of "Foundation models". If you want one, the best place to go would be [this paper from Stanford that coined the term](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07258). Generally at least some of the following ideas apply (according to some people they must all apply, according to others only some need to apply):

- Trained using unsupervised or self-supervised learning.
- Large (deep neural network) model.
- Not intended to be used directly for any particular end-goal.
- Intended to serve as a basis ("foundation"). You can think of this as "warm-starting", starting from a well-trained initial model, that you can then fine-tune with further training (for example, supervised learning) for any specific task you personally have in mind.
- Trained on multimodal data (not just text, not just images, not just audio, etc., but a mix of things). *In my personal opinion this point really is not strictly necessary, and I think most people would agree, but I've seen some people saying this.*

Large Language Models would typically be trained specifically on language-related data (text). So, I suppose an LLM could sometimes serve as a Foundation model, but it's not necessarily the same thing.

**NOTE**: I would like to remark that, from many experts outside of Stanford, there is [quite a bit of pushback against the particular term "Foundation model"](https://twitter.com/tdietterich/status/1558256704696905728). There seems to be a bit of PR involved, where it seems like they may like to coin a new term for something that really doesn't need a new term. Just saying it's, for example, a [large pre-trained model](https://twitter.com/raphaelmilliere/status/1558460796321021953), may be more clear.